# geopanadas' to_file method generating TypeError when trying to export a geodataframe to geojson

Tags: python, geopandas

I have the following geodataframe:

|  | zip2 | geometry | centroid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01 | POLYGON ((-73.22397 42.04480, -73.22865 42.044... | POINT (-72.20433 42.40904) |
| 1 | 02 | MULTIPOLYGON (((-71.59455 41.20118, -71.59286 ... | POINT (-71.05764 41.82122) |
| 2 | 03 | MULTIPOLYGON (((-72.08604 42.71645, -72.08932 ... | POINT (-71.53581 43.72449) |
| : | : | : | : |

When I try to export it to a geojson, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret '<geopandas.array.GeometryDtype object at 0x0000020BA3E3C670>' as a data type
```

I am at my wits trying to debug this one. Can someone please help me resolve this error?

I have checked the dataframe in every which way

gdf.dtypes output:

```
zip2          object
geometry    geometry
centroid    geometry
```

gdf.is_valid output:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
10    True
11    True
```

gdf.crs output:

```
<Geographic 2D CRS: EPSG:4269>
Name: NAD83
Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:
- Lat[north]: Geodetic latitude (degree)
- Lon[east]: Geodetic longitude (degree)
Area of Use:
- name: North America - onshore and offshore: Canada - Alberta; British Columbia; Manitoba; New Brunswick; Newfoundland and Labrador; Northwest Territories; Nova Scotia; Nunavut; Ontario; Prince Edward Island; Quebec; Saskatchewan; Yukon. Puerto Rico. United States (USA) - Alabama; Alaska; Arizona; Arkansas; California; Colorado; Connecticut; Delaware; Florida; Georgia; Hawaii; Idaho; Illinois; Indiana; Iowa; Kansas; Kentucky; Louisiana; Maine; Maryland; Massachusetts; Michigan; Minnesota; Mississippi; Missouri; Montana; Nebraska; Nevada; New Hampshire; New Jersey; New Mexico; New York; North Carolina; North Dakota; Ohio; Oklahoma; Oregon; Pennsylvania; Rhode Island; South Carolina; South Dakota; Tennessee; Texas; Utah; Vermont; Virginia; Washington; West Virginia; Wisconsin; Wyoming. US Virgin Islands. British Virgin Islands.
- bounds: (167.65, 14.92, -40.73, 86.45)
Datum: North American Datum 1983
- Ellipsoid: GRS 1980
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

Comment: How may we help you resolve this error?

Comment: What is causing this error and how can I get a .geojson output from this geodataframe?

Comment: Can you show the minimum amount of code needed that lets us recreate this geodataframe?

Comment: And if you have found the solution, can you please post it as an answer instead of including it in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was trying to write multiple geometry columns using to_file. According to [this](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/2566), I cannot have multiple geometry columns and the error messaging is being improved to convey this more clearly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).